# Cannot SSH to ec2 instance in VPC

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, nat, amazon-vpc

I'm just starting with AWS, and have 2 ec2 instances running on a VPC, one with a public and private IP, one with only a private IP.

I can SSH to both (using my key) if I attach an external IP to them.

I can SSH from server 1 to server 2 (if I copy the pem key onto server 1)

Server 2 I want to be private IP only, and server 1 has a public IP and NAT to server 2. I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://cloudpages.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/ssh-to-an-instance-in-private-subnet/) aws shows the private address of server 2 to be 10.0.0.18 (server 1 is 10.0.0.63)

On server 1 I have added..

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10235 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.18:22
```

if I look at the tables, I can see...

```
1    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10235 to:10.0.0.18:22
```

And if I look at packets for iptables...

```
iptables -L -v -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 40 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   10   600 DNAT       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10235 to:10.0.0.18:22
```

I am trying to connect with...

```
ssh -i mykeyfile.pem -p 10235 user@<server1domain>
```

Whenever I try, I can see the packets increase on server 1, but I never get any response. I have allowed port 10234&5 & 22 on the security group.

Security group shows as..

```
  Custom TCP Rule TCP 10234 - 10240 0.0.0.0/0
```

ssh -vvv doesn't provide anything useful, as its just hanging saying 'connecting to myhost port 10235.

As mentioned, if I associate a public IP and connect to that, all works, but I can't seem to get it working via NAT ?

Comment: Did you disable source/dest checking on your NAT instance?

Comment: Do you mean in the security group (or is there somewhere I'm not aware of on the box itself)? Ie in the security group I've set it to have source 0.0.0.0/0 I have added that display into the question as well.

Comment: No, this is a setting on the instance itself. Look through the Actions menu in the console.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't spotted that. I have disabled it on both for the moment whilst testing and its still the same though. Just to clarify though, I'm not using a specific NAT instance, just a regular front end server with a public IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect from outside the VPC to the instance with only a a private IP, this will fail. You will want to setup your instance with the public ip to also be a VPN (try OpenVPN AS) and then allow ssh access that way.

If you are trying to SSH from server 2 (private IP only) to server 1 (public/private) then you may need to also add a route table or security group as well as making sure the VPC can handle NAT/PAT traffic:

[NAT/PAT Script](https://gist.github.com/jlawsonb/245c3e9b71fd8e94c5df#file-configure-pat-sh)

And set it up to run (ubuntu):

```
sed -i '$ i '"/usr/local/sbin/configure-pat.sh"'' /etc/rc.local'
```